# the app is crashing saying stack overflow

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
i obseved that the app is crashing after i add that listview builder if we dont add that app running smoothly
```

i am still a new bee so i dont know much i just started

if u want u can see whole app code in
https://github.com/Pradeep7976/E_com_app/tree/master/shop_app

this is a garbage i am writing this cause stack overflow is suggesting to add more description   it is saying the post is mostly code add some more description

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart' show Cart;
import '../widgets/cart_item.dart';
import '../providers/orders.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/cart';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your Cart'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Chip(
                    label: Text(
                      '₹${cart.totalAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('ORDER NOW'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Provider.of<Orders>(context, listen: false).addOrder(
                        cart.items.values.toList(),
                        cart.totalAmount,
                      );

                      cart.clear();
                    },
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItem(
                cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
                cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
                cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                cart.items.values.toList()[i].title,
              ),
              itemCount: cart.items.length,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.  Without it we're left guessing why it crashed.

Answer (score -1):

this happens when there is an infinite loop in your app
perhaps your problem is the number of cart items which tries to build so many widgets

Comment: but i have given item count how can it build so many widgets